# ReactiveMongo: Projection element not return using reactive mongo query

Tags: mongodb, scala, mongodb-query, reactivemongo

i have following mongodb document:

```
{
"_id" : ObjectId("5592c0e6ea16e552ac90e169"),
-----------
"location" : {
    "_id" : ObjectId("5592c17fc3ad8cbffa0e9778"),
    "companyFieldId" : ObjectId("559140f1ea16e552ac90e058"),
    "name" : "Location",
    "alias" : "Points",
    "locations" : [ 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5592c17fc3ad8cbffa0e9779"),
            "country" : "India",
            "state" : "Punjab",
            "city" : "Moga",
            "zip" : "142001",
            "custom" : false
        }, 
        {
            "_id" : ObjectId("5592c17fc3ad8cbffa0e977a"),
            "country" : "India da address",
            "custom" : true
        }
    ],
    "mandatory" : true,
    "allowForGroups" : false
},
-----------
}
```

When i query the document using following query:

```
companyCollection.find($doc("_id" $eq companyId, "location._id" $eq locationId)).projection($doc("location" -> 1, "_id" -> 1)).cursor[LocationField].headOption;
```

It will return only `company id`. But when i change the projection value to `projection($doc("location" -> 1, "_id" -> 0))` it return empty document. I am using [Query DSL](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo-Extensions/blob/0.10.x/guide/dsl.md) for write the queries.

**UPDATE**

When i create query like:

```
companyCollection.find($doc("_id" $eq companyId, "department._id" $eq departmentId), $doc("department" -> 1, "_id" -> 0)).cursor[Company].headOption
```

with this my return value is map with `Company` and with its property `LocationField` using projection and rest of the fields are ignore by mongodb. But my basic requirement is return only `location` inner document value and map with `LocationField`. When i run query in mongo db console like :

```
db.companies.find({"_id": ObjectId('5592c0e6ea16e552ac90e169'), "location._id": ObjectId('5592c17fc3ad8cbffa0e9778')}, {"location": 1, "_id": 0})
```

The result behavior is same as my reactive mongo query. Is it possible with mongo db for return only inner document, instead of full document structure?

Comment: Try without the DSL. Note that this extension is not compatible with 0.11.

Comment: The [unit tests](https://github.com/ReactiveMongo/ReactiveMongo/blob/0.10.5.x.akka23/driver/src/test/scala/BSONCollectionSpec.scala#L66) of the driver (versions 0.10.5.x and 0.11.0) confirm that the projection document is used.

Comment: hello @cchantep i am using `"org.reactivemongo" % "reactivemongo_2.11" % "0.10.5.0.akka23"` and with this, query DSL is possible with reactive mongo and it is run as i mention in above update section.

Comment: As mentioned just before, the unit tests of the driver, 0.10.5.x or 0.11.0 indicate that the project document is properly used. So I suggest you try to test your query without the DSL, with plain `BSONDocument`.